# XeLaTeX with Polyglossia and Thai

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, languages, polyglossia

The following example displays the English text alright, but not the Thai text. It is simply left blank in the PDF result.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\newfontfamily\thaifont{Norasi}
\newfontfamily\thaifontsf{Loma}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\begin{document}
Here comes some Thai: สารบัญ

{\sffamily Here comes some Thai: สารบัญ}
\end{document}
```

If I change the `\setdefaultlanguage` to thai, it works, but that's not the idea as this is an English document.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are nowhere telling xelatex that you wish to switch to thai. Use either
`\setotherlanguage{thai}` and `\selectlanguage{thai}`, or at least use the `\thaifont` command.

Comment: I thought the whole idea of Unicode input in XeLaTeX was that XeLaTeX "just works" with that. In any case, I've added the `\setotherlanguage{thai}` line but that has no effect. Your other suggestions require that I know in advance that the following text actually will be in Thai. In my case, that's not practical as I process unknown text automatically.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. `\setotherlanguage{thai}` obviously only works together with `\selectlanguage{thai}`. Yes, that works. But unfortunately leaves me with the problem that I would have to know where in the text the Thai script is sitting. I guess the solution would be to find a rather complete unicode font that has the scripts like Thai covered and use that as main font.

Comment: It is possible (with `\XeTeXintercharclass`/`\XeTeXinterchartoks`) to setup things so that XeTeX automatically switch to another font.

Comment: That's interesting! This lead me to the ucharclasses package, which doesn't seem to be part of the large standard distributions. A simple `\setTransitionTo{Thai}{\fontspec{Norasi}}` does the trick. Unfortunately, the package seems to be very computationally intensive as it makes the whole process quite slow.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this! It helped me a lot, but it still required some experiments to get it working. Hence, I would like to contribute a functional example here:

File **letter-preamble-th.tex**

```
%%% IMPORTANT --- must be compiled with XeLaTeX!!! %%%

\documentclass[a4paper,
footsepline,
pagenumber=botcenter,
fromalign=left,
fromrule=below,
fromemail=true,
subject=untitled,
locfield=narrow,
foldmarks=true,
11pt
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{thai}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\newfontfamily\thaifont{Norasi}
\newfontfamily\thaifontsf{Loma}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,.5}
\definecolor{darkgrey}{rgb}{0.3,0.3,0.3}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true, linkcolor=darkblue, menucolor=darkblue, urlcolor=darkblue]{hyperref}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-.53cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{363pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{690pt}

% Zum Testen
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
%\isodate


\firsthead{% 
  \color{darkgrey}
  \hfill
  \parbox[t]{0.25\textwidth}{
    \raggedright{
      \vspace*{0.46cm} % offset for align the top border with the head of the wizard
      \footnotesize
      \usekomavar{fromname}\\
      \usekomavar{fromaddress}\\\smallskip
      \usekomavar{fromemail}\\\smallskip

      \scriptsize
    PGP-Fingerprint\\
    \texttt{1CB2 35C8 F3B0 236A C46D}\\ 
    \texttt{38FB 289F 1C57 2BA1 020C}\\
    }%
  }
}%

% Header for all other pages
\nexthead{
  \parbox[t]{.2\textwidth}{
\scriptsize\usekomavar{fromname}
  }\hfill
  \parbox[t]{.4\textwidth}{
    \scriptsize\usekomavar{subject}
  }\hfill
  \parbox[t]{.4\textwidth}{
    \hfill\scriptsize\usekomavar{toname}
  }
}

\firstfoot{%
  \color{darkgrey}
  \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\scriptsize
    %\centering
    %\parbox[t]{.2\textwidth}
    Example footer | {\selectlanguage{thai}ติดต่อ ประชาสัมพันธ์มหาวิทยาลัยเชียงใหม่} \\
    And some more Thai: {\selectlanguage{thai}มหาวิทยาลัยเชียงใหม่} |  More nonsense: TH 245\,111\,222\\
    Some people or companies put their bank coordinates here in the footer -- hence this example\\
  }%
}%



% Sender
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{{\selectlanguage{thai}239 ถนนห้วยแก้ว}\\{\selectlanguage{thai}ต.สุเทพ อ.เมือง}\\{\selectlanguage{thai}จ.เชียงใหม่ 50200}\\Thailand}


\setkomavar{fromemail}{\href{mailto:marco@domain.tld}{marco@domain.tld}}
% \setkomavar{fromlogo}{\adjustbox{valign=t}{
%   \hspace{-1.1cm} % Offset for align the center of the wizard with the text
%   \includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{img/logo.png}}}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Marco {\selectlanguage{thai}หงุ่ยตระกูล}}
```

File **example-letter-th.tex**

```
%%% IMPORTANT --- must be compiled with XeLaTeX!!! %%%

\input{letter-preamble-th.tex}

\setkomavar{date}{ 2015-04-27 }

\setkomavar{subject}{Example letter English/{\selectlanguage{thai}ไทย} (Thai)}

\newcommand{\openingText}{Dear Ladies, dear Sirs,}

\newcommand{\closingText}{Yours sincerely,}
\setkomavar{signature}{Marco {\selectlanguage{thai}หงุ่ยตระกูล}-Schulze}





\renewcommand*{\adrentry}[8]{
  \begin{letter}{#2 #1\\#3}
    \opening{\openingText}

this is an example letter using English and Thai -- mixed {\selectlanguage{thai}พสกนิกรสุดปลื้มปีติ} like this.

Unfortunately, it is necessary to switch explicitly to Thai using:
``\{\textbackslash{}selectlanguage\{thai\}XXX\}'' where ``XXX''
are Thai letters. I read some hints that XeLaTeX is able to switch the language (and thus the font!) automatically,
but I didn't want to invest more time into this topic -- and this solution works fine (at least for now).

    \closing{\closingText}
  \end{letter}
}



\begin{document}
%\layout

\pagestyle{myheadings}

% Multiple entries can be used to easily create a serial letter
% Only last name, first name and address are currently used
\adrentry{{\selectlanguage{thai}รอยัล  ออร์คิด พลัส\\บริษัท การบินไทย จำกัด (มหาชน)}}{}{{\selectlanguage{thai}ตู้ปณ. 567 ไปรษณีย์ สามเสนใน\\กรุงเทพฯ 10400}}{Telefon}{F1}{F2}{Kommentar}{ADDR}
\end{document}
```

Just in case, the above code was not pasted correctly, I uploaded it for you -- both the sources and the generated PDF: [example-letter-th.zip](https://codewizards.co/mn/2015-05-06_XeLaTeX_Thai_Letter/example-letter-th.zip)

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: Is that a question, or an answer? Why is there so much code? The example is muddled.